# Change language from Swedish to English QGIS pisa

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.10, internationalization

Can I change language from Swedish to English in my QGIS Pisa?

I don't remember even choosing languages when I installed it.

Answer (score 8):

If you go to *Inställningar > Alternativ... > Lokalisering*, you can change the locale:

[image: Locale]

Comment: +1, in my hurry I read the question as eng->swe not the other way round.

Answer (score 7):

it's also possible to specify the language at the command line when you launch QGIS, e.g. for English and French,

```
qgis --lang en
qgis --lang fr
```

This can also be useful if you changed to a language you can't read by mistake (or out of curiosity) and need to be able to find your settings again ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**Settings** --> **Options** --> **Locale**

There you can select any locale that QGIS supports. The standard behaviour is to use the system default, so I am guessing you are using a Swedish Windows(?).

[image]